# set theory - families

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am learning set theory and am currently trying to understand the chapter on families in Naive set theory by Halmos.

He writes:

> Suppose, for instance that $x$ is a function from a set $I$ to a set $X$.
>       An element of the domain $I$ is called an index, $I$ is called the index set, the range of the function is called an indexed set, the function itself is called a family, and the value of the function $x$ at and index $i$, called a term of the family, is denoted by $x_i$.
>
> .......speak of a family $\{x_i\}$ in X.

Say I = {1,2,3} and X = {4,5,6}
Is the family = {x1,x2,x3}? OR are there 3 families {x1},{x2},{x3}?

What am I missing here

Thanks,

Comment: I don't see any function here.

Comment: x is a function

Comment: I see no function $x$ in your examples.

Comment: Say I = {1,2,3} and X = {4,5,6} Is the family = {x1,x2,x3}? OR are there 3 families {x1},{x2},{x3}?......there's 6 lol

Comment: $\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$ *doesn't mean anything* unless you specify the function $x$ first.

Comment: x  is a function from a set I to a set X

Comment: Yes, but WHICH function? It looks like you're trying to set up an example, but you don't give the one piece of information the example needs. So *nothing* in the example you're attempting above is an indexed family.

Comment: hmm I'm confused I have no idea what I've written above is what he writes in the book

Comment: Is the part starting "Say I = {1,2,3} and X = {4,5,6}..." from the book? Or is this part of an example that you're trying to set up?

Comment: No that's my example but I'm confused as to what I'm missing

Comment: You're missing a specification of $x$ the way you specify what $I$ and $X$ are.

Comment: what about xi=i?

Comment: That's a perfectly good example of an indexed family. It might be called a trivial indexing, but it counts. Assuming $I\subset X$, of course.

Comment: so X would equal {1,2,3}?

Comment: $X$ could be a much larger set. The *set indexed by $I$* would be $\{1,2,3\}$, but the set indexed by $I$ only needs to be a *subset* of $X$.

Comment: Hm I don't understand, can you provide an example? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I provide two examples in my answer. In the first one, $X$ is *all* the natural numbers; there are only three numbers $n$ such that $n=x_i$ for some $i$.

Comment: Is the set indexed by I always a subset of X? What is the point of defining X?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say $I=\{1,2,3\}$ and $X=\mathbb{N}$. If $x$ is the function defined on $I$ such that $x_i=i+3$ then, in the terminology you quote, $x$ is the family, $\{4,5,6\}$ is the set *indexed by* $I$.

Another example would be $I=\mathbb{N}$ and $X=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ and $x_i=\{m:\exists y(y\in\mathbb{N}\wedge m=y^i)\}$. That is, the term $x_i$ at each index $i$ is the set of all natural numbers that are the $i$-th power of something.

Simply specifying $I$ and $X$ doesn't uniquely determine an indexed family; such families are an extra piece of information, namely a function $x:I\to X$.

Comment: what do you mean i+3?

Comment: "$x_i$" is just another way to write $x(i)$, the application of the function $x$ to an element $i\in I$.

Comment: So $x(i)=i+3$, is exactly the same sort of thing as $f(x)=x+3$, just a different choice of letters.

Comment: but why the number 3?

Comment: It's arbitrary. It's just an example.

Comment: Instead I could set $x_i=2i+1$, then the set indexed by $i$ is $\{3,5,7\}$. That would be another example of indexing.

Comment: ohhhhh right thank you that helps! so xi has to be assigned a value?

Comment: At least in principle. If you want to give an example of an indexed family, you need to say what it does with each $i$ you input. You can also reason about them abstractly without knowing how they're defined, but there may not be much to say about them.